# Closing ngx-bootstrap Modal from another service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngx-bootstrap

I have a `openModal()` method in `ShowLoginModalService` , and the `ShowLoginModalService` class contains this particular code:

### ShowLoginModalService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginDialogComponent } from '@shared/common/component/login-dialog/login-dialog.component';

import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ShowLoginModalService {
    constructor(private bsModalService: BsModalService) {}
    private bsModalRef: BsModalRef;

    openLoginModal(prevUrl: string) {
        this.bsModalRef = this.bsModalService.show(LoginDialogComponent, {
            class: 'modal-xl modal-dialog-centered login-modal',
            id: 1,
        });
    }
}
```

I have loginService that does the login logic and within it , i declared a method which returns an Observable when the user is logged in.

### in Login Service

```
processAuthenticateResult(authenticateResult: AuthenticateResultModel, redirectUrl?: string){
this.authenticateResult = authenticateResult;

if (authenticateResult.requiresTwoFactorVerification) {
            // Two factor authentication
            this.isLoggedIn(authenticateResult).subscribe(
                (result) => {
                    this.bsModalService.hide(1);
                    console.log(result);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log('Error');
                },
            );
            this._router.navigate(['account/send-code']);
        }
}


public isLoggedIn(authResult): Observable<boolean> {
        let Observable= new Observable<boolean>((observer) => {
            switch (authResult) {
                case authResult.accessToken && authResult.encryptedAccessToken:
                    observer.next(true);
                    break;

                default:
                    observer.next(false);
            }
            observer.unsubscribe();
        });

        return subject;
    }
```

the LoginDialogComponent's Template contains this code:

```
<div class="modal-body w-100 h-100">
    <iframe [src]="loginFrame" *ngIf="displayLoginFrame" id="login-frame" class="w-100 h-100"></iframe>
</div>
```

my **Main Problem** is how can i close the opened modal using bsModalService?

i tried giving the modal an id and then call the `bsModalService.hide()` method in LoginService using a given unique id but it does not anything and when i try to give the `bsModalRef` in ShowLoginModalService an id it throws an error

Comment: Which version of `ngx-bootstrap` are you using? By any means are you importing `ModalModule` in multiple NgModule?

Comment: @Siddhant , I'm using 6.2.0 version , and no the ModalModule is just imported in the utils module which is a shared module between other modules